# UIImage convert to data and back changes size?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I create a picture programmatically, convert it to data and back and get different pictures.

```
    let image1: UIImage = {
        let size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        UIColor.black.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }()
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1)!
    let image2 = UIImage(data: data)!
    print(image1.size) // (50.0, 50.0)
    print(image2.size) // (100.0, 100.0)
```

Please explain what happens and how to solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Read the documentation of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()`, ask yourself why you set `0` for the last parameter. Ask yourself if your device is Retina (x2), and you should get the answer.

Comment: @Larme I realized. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "culprit" line:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
```

Looking at the doc of [`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623912-uigraphicsbeginimagecontextwitho?language=objc), for the last parameter (`scale`)

> **scale** 
> The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. *If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the
>   device’s main screen.*

If your device is Retina (*2), then the scale factor will be 2.